# Can I use either Store or CT for event product hire/rent?

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob

Just wondered if anyone had previously used either CT or Store for product hire or rent.

I have a potential project that requires the following:

1. The client has a contract to supply wheelchairs to events at a particular venue. This service could develop to cover more venues across the UK so the system should be designed to include multiple venues, events and dates.
2. Client manages the listing and adds events by location, event title and date. The client selects which items can be available at each location. Visitors can search by keyword, event, location or date and will be shown a list of results that can be filtered. Or alternatively, they could choose a product and then the event.
3. Once an event is chosen, the client can choose which item/product they would like to hire and go through the purchase process.
4. The system will log the booking and send confirmation emails to the customer. The site could also check stock levels and either show ‘out of stock’ when the limit is reached or send an email notice to the client.

I'm just looking for pointers as to the best way to achieve the above using one of the add-ons mentioned.

Relationships could be used to assign products to venues, it's assigning the product to the event in some way that decreases the stock level only for that product for that event etc.

I have good experience of using both but not in this way, so I imagine I might require some custom code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like something Store could handle. Essentially you're able to sell any Channel Entry so you just need to add our single Store Product Details Field to any Channel Group to make it sellable and everything else fits right into EE and your desired workflow.

The only thing to keep it mind however is that if you have one product available at multiple events then each of those would require a different stock level. In this case you couldn't accomplish this with relationships because each 'product' can only have a single stock level. You'd need to list the product for each event but you're still able to organise this however you prefer to, whether it be to have a Category for each event or a Channel etc. It would essentially mean having duplicate products in the system but this will allow you to firmly control the stock for each event and satisfy your 4th point above ensuring more aren't sold per event than are available.

Comment: Building on this, could you not have a channel for "Product Information" and a channel for "Product Instance"? You could use Instance for stock, but relate an instance back to information to share the description, photograph, reviews, etc.

Comment: Potentially you could do something like that if you really wanted to but you'd still be managing two Channel Entries in two different Channels for one product then so you wouldn't gain a lot unless you had enough events to make it worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. The only downside in your solution Ian, as you say is the duplicates, however it's not the end of the world so long as it's managed correctly.